# videojs & iPhone // Works fine on ie7-9 + iPad, but no iPhone

Tags: html, html5-video

Working with videojs has been a bit of a house of cards. Rearrange the order & the video breaks in IE. Change the codex and the videos break on iPad.

Can anyone point me to a clean setup that truly works cross browser & which video codex work? I'm currently delivering MP4.h26 + OGG + WebM. Works great for everything except iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server has to support the `Byte-Range` header, as explained here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html

Answer (score 0):

Zencoder have [a useful guide on how to encode for a variety of devices](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/guides/encoding-settings/ios-and-mobile).

Their advice applies to any encoding software, not just their own encoding service.